# Yii has many through ajax validation

Tags: php, yii

```
public function actionEquipmentLoanRequestCreate()
{



    if(isset($_POST['EquipmentRequest']))
    {
        $ids = $_POST['EquipmentRequest']['equipID'];
        $equipment = Equipment::model()->findAllByPk($ids);
        $requests = self::instantiateEquipmentRequests($equipment);
        //echo "<pre>";
        //die(count($requests)." ".CActiveForm::validate($requests));


        $booking = new EquipmentBooking;



        if(isset($_POST['EquipmentRequest']) && $_POST['EquipmentBooking'])
        {
            $booking->attributes = $_POST['EquipmentBooking'];
            $requestPostedVars = $_POST['EquipmentRequest'];
            //have posted collection of equipment
            //need to take count
            //request below not really useful???
            $equipmentRequests = array();
            foreach($requestPostedVars as $request)
            {
                if(isset($request))
                {
                    $equipmentRequest = new EquipmentRequest('loanRequest');
                    $equipmentRequest->attributes = $request;
                    array_push($equipmentRequests,$equipmentRequest);


                }

            }
            $models = $equipmentRequests;
            $models[]=$booking;
            $this->performAjaxValidation($models);
            $booking->equipment = $equipmentRequests;
            if ($booking->save()){
                self::assignBookingIds($equipmentRequests,$booking);
                $this->redirect('index');
            }


        }
        //displays view to create loan request
        $this->render('equipment-loan-request',array('requests' => $requests,'booking' => $booking));  


    } else {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "You need to select equipment first!");
            $this->redirect(array('simulation/equipment'), true);
    }


}

public function instantiateEquipmentRequests($equipment)
{
    $equipmentRequests = array();
    foreach($equipment as $item)
    {
        $request = new EquipmentRequest('loanRequest');
        $request->equipment = $item;
        $request->qty = 1;

        array_push($equipmentRequests,$request);
    }
    return $equipmentRequests;
}
```

**form view** ignore excess button replacing later -- ive directly tried calling the requests as opposed to just the bookings or both below as well to no avail.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveFormExtended', array(
        'id' => 'equipment-booking-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
          'validateOnSubmit' => true,
          'validateOnChange'=>true,

          ),

  )); ?>
  <div class="content-bg">        

  <?php 
  echo  $form->errorSummary($requests); 



   if(isset($requests) && count($requests) > 0) {
          foreach($requests as $i => $request) { 
            $this->renderPartial('_requestedEquipment', array("index" => $i, "request" => $request, "form"=> $form)); 
          }
        }?>
  </div>
  <br />


  <hr class="brown"/>



    <h2>Request Details</h2>
    <div class="content-bg">
      <h3>Step 1</h3>
      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'organisation'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->dropDownList($booking, 'organisation', $booking::$organisations,array('id' => 'organisation', 'class' => "selectfield",'empty' => 'Select')); ?>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="content-bg">
      <h3>Step 2</h3>
      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'name'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($booking,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'name'); ?>

      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'email'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($booking,'email',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'email'); ?>

      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'phone'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($booking,'phone',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'phone'); ?>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="content-bg">
      <h3>Step 3</h3>
      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'address'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($booking,'address',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'address'); ?>

      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'suburb'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($booking,'suburb',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'suburb'); ?>

      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'postcode'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($booking,'postcode',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'postcode'); ?>

    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="content-bg">
      <h3>Step 4</h3>
      <div class="five columns alpha">
      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'pickupDate'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->dropDownDayList($booking, 'pickupDate',array('class' => 'date-day pickup_select','id' => 'pickup')); ?>
      <?php echo $form->dropDownYearList($booking,1, 'pickupDate',array('class' => 'date-monthyear pickup_select','id' => 'pickup-month')); ?>
      <?php echo $form->hiddenField($booking, 'pickupDate',array('id' => 'pickupData')); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'pickupDate'); ?>

      </div>
      <div class="five columns alpha">
      <?php echo $form->label($booking,'returnDate'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->dropDownDayList($booking, 'returnDate',array('class' => 'date-day return_select','id' => 'return')); ?>
      <?php echo $form->dropDownYearList($booking,1, 'returnDate',array('class' => 'date-monthyear return_select','id' => 'return-month')); ?>
      <?php echo $form->hiddenField($booking, 'returnDate',array('id' => 'returnData')); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($booking,'returnDate'); ?>

      </div>
      <br class="clear"/>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="content-bg">
      <h2>Terms &amp; Conditions</h2>
      <p>By submitting this loan enquiry you agree to and acknowledge our <a href="equiploanterms">Equipment Loan Terms and Conditions</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
    <br />
<input class="orange-btn right" type="submit" value="Submit Loan Request">

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
    </div>
```

**EquipmentRequest partial**

```
<div class="selected-equipment" id="request_<?php echo $request->equipment->equipName; ?>">
<div class="equipment-selected"><a href="#"><?php echo $request->equipment->equipName; ?></a></div>
    <div class="equipment-qty"><?php echo $form->textField($request, "[$index]qty", array('value' => 1,'class' => 'requestQuantity')); ?></div>
    <?php echo $form->error($request,"[$index]qty"); ?>

    <div class="equipment-update"><a href="#" class="brown-btn small"><span>Remove</span></a></div>
    <?php echo $form->hiddenField($request, "[$index]equipID",array('value' => $request->equipment->equipID)); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($request,"[$index]equipID"); ?>

    <br class="clear">
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Please note I have rectified the above issue. Was mainly caused by an incorrect usage of performAjaxValidate, which I have now set to call both the booking and the collection of equipmentRequests.

This is now letting me get 2 validation error message objects back, 1 for both models. however only the booking model is being passed to the error summary div.

@bool.dev appreciate your assistance so far, any ideas with the above, have tried merging the collection of equipment request objects and booking object to the one argument call in errorSummary

I've edited the above to show updated controller actions and views

Comment: how does it not recognize equipId? what's the exact error?

Comment: you can comment here, and let me know

Comment: I've gotten it to the stage where im now receiving correct validation errors against both model. But so far the only errors showing in the actual form are for the booking, not the equipment request.

Will update the question above with the details

Comment: ok...if you want to message me use @bool.dev so that i'm notified

Answer (score 1):

When you want [`errorSummary()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#errorSummary-detail) for more than one model, use:

```
$form->errorSummary(array($model1,$model2,$model3));
```

Comment: Have tried that directly @bool.dev with my object collection : array_push($equipmentRequests,$equipmentRequest);

so when I call errorSummary have called directly on the array via
errorSummary($equipmentRequests);
as well as errorSummary(array($equipmentRequests))

get null object error using the array method. 

Wierd bit is im definitely getting two separate objects from the ajax validation call and theyre all correct.

Comment: I have updated the question above with the changed structure, hope this helps. Happy to provide extra info where possible.

Comment: yeah now the structure of the question looks better suited to the current issue

Comment: no worries. Have thrown in the instantiateEquipmentRequests for good measure. Basically its a 3 part form where in the first instance the user selects the equipment before moving onto the next stage. I'm utilising the 'loanRequest' scenario so I don't get bugged about missing booking id's before saving.

Comment: what happens when you fill the booking correctly, and equipment incorrectly? do you get the errors then? btw, if you are using array_push, then ofcourse you'll directly pass the variable, and not use array($variable)

Comment: Combination. On field change getting error message in json return (checking through chrome console), but booking still successfully saves.

Comment: giving up for now! if i come up with something, i'll let you know,  i'll try and recreate a similar scenario and see. can't find any error in your code atm.

Comment: hehe, haven't been of much help till now, but you are welcome

Comment: one more thing, you are getting json for onchange, but not onsubmit?

Comment: edit, scratch that, double checked, getting json for onsubmit

Comment: so the problem is that even if you get json for onsubmit, the errorSummary doesn't show those errors(equipment no show, booking show)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12845/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-ridget)